# Test for rows on linked Oracle server from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get a syntax error with this TSQL:

```
if exists ( exec('select * from mytable') at LinkedOracleServer ) begin
    print 'rows exist'
end
```

I can't use INSERT EXEC into a temp table because the calling proc also uses INSERT EXEC and I get the error "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested."

Is there another way to test for existing rows on a linked server?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a suggestion. Can't you try like this

```
select @recod_count = count(*) from LinkedOracleServer.mytable
if @recod_count>1 begin
end
```